# How can I implement Spring Boot Security Jwt login and logout using Redis

Tags: spring, security, redis, jwt, boot

I am facing a challenge implementing Spring Boot Security Jwt login and logout using Redis. I have been able to do login and token generation without the use of Redis but however I need to implement login & logout mechanism for my rest-api using Redis such that I will be able to invalidate (blacklist at logout) the jwt token even before its has not expired yet. I am able to the create the Redis Config file only but beyond that I am stuck.

Comment: Please provide enough code that you have done so far, so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. I have created a sample project and its on Github Link: https://github.com/omudzingwa/spring-security-jwt-redis-login-logout-demo and I copied that same project from the following Github link https://github.com/JianChoi-Kor/Login/ but mine is failing to compile with errors described in the Github ReadMe File. Kindly check and help.

Comment: Hi. I have been able to find a fix and the program compliles by simply changing: SecretKey secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64URL.decode(secret)); to SecretKey secretKey = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256); although the later is deprecated.